# Javascript OnMouseOver without attribute

Tags: javascript, html, dom, drop-down-menu, onmouseover

I'm trying to trigger a javascript onMouseOver event without having the onMouseOver attribute on everyone of my anchor attributes. In reality I want to display some other anchors when the user mouses over an element, but I can't even get an alert to work. I keep getting the error of:

`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'getElementsByTagName' of null`

Which doesn't make sense to me because if I alert out the `getElementById()` I end up with a DIV element, which it should then get all the anchor tags inside that div element... Not sure what I am missing.

JSFiddle Link: http://jsfiddle.net/NfTtq/

Also note I am doing this Javascript not JQuery :S

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are trying to find the element before it exists, you can do this in jsfiddle by selecting `onDomReady` from the left instead of `no wrap (head)`

The other problem is `onMouseOver`, javascript is case sensitive so only `onmouseover` will work.

Here is updated jsfiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/NfTtq/1/

Comment: Ohhhhh that makes sense, reading it from top to bottom ok ok. Is there a javascript way to tell if the document is ready without having something in the body? document.ready() or something?

Comment: just run your element dependant javascript right before </body> tag.. this way the code is only found after all elements in the page and they exist when the code is executed. `$(document).ready(fn)` is jQuery, there is no cross browser equivalent in plain javascript.

Comment: putting it in the footer worked. :D Thanks will remember this in future!

Comment: Yes, just before `</body>` tag you put `<script type="text/javascript"></script>` and inside the script tag you put the code and it should work.

Answer (score 1):

You are executing script before html is loaded, so you need to put it into window.onload

http://jsfiddle.net/NfTtq/5/

```
window.onload= function()
    {

      var node = document.getElementById('navFloat').getElementsByTagName('a');
      node[0].onmouseover = function()
        {
            alert('yes');
            document.getElementById('homeDrop').style.display = 'block';            
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The onMouseDown event is written in small caps only, when invoked on the DOM. This worked for me:

```
var node = document.getElementById('navFloat').getElementsByTagName('a');
node[0].onmouseover= function()
{
    document.getElementById('homeDrop').style.display = 'block';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

this code will work on all browsers.....

```
<p>
<a href="/">
<img alt="Ovdje uključiti " 
src="errorimages/normal.png" 
onmouseover="this.src='errorimages/hover.png'" 
onmousedown="this.src='errorimages/press.png'" 
onmouseup="this.src='errorimages/hover.png'" 
onmouseout="this.src='errorimages/normal.png'"
></a>
</p>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Could you please [edit] in an explanation of why this code answers the question?